# VBA OUTLOOK - PropertyChange Gets Activated By MsgBox Multiple Times

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing a multi-purpose code in ThisOutlookSession, one part of the code has the job to get activated by PropertyChange in CurrentItem and if Subject is equal to a specific value, it first opens a MsgBox, on VBYes it Copies a value that is stored inside a .txt file and opens a mail with an .HTMLBody with that value.

It works fine if in the MsgBox input you answer VbYes, but if you answer VbNo then the PropertyChange is activated 3 times, in this case I have to answer 3 times VbNo.

I can actually see that the appearence of the MsgBox triggers the m_inspector_activate() which makes the code think that the Subject changed another time (this is how I think it works).

I will leave a shortened part of the code to let you see what I'am talking about.

Please text me if you do not understand something.

```
Option Explicit

'global variable used to disable the trigger of oItem_Forward(), oItem_Reply() and oItem_ReplyAll() while myItem_PropertyChange() is working

Public disableevents As Boolean


'private variables used to display mailitem on Reply, ReplyAll or Forward

Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem

'private variables used ad inspectors in PropertyChange and ItemSend

Private WithEvents m_Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents m_Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
Private WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem


'declaration necessary to manage the forwards, replies and replyall events, recognizes the discard

Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean

'declaration of variable that manages the forwards, replies and replyall events

Dim exception As MailItem

'sub activated by opening outlook, it sets the inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()

     Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
     Set m_Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
     
     bDiscardEvents = False
     
End Sub

'sub that on change of item selection, sets and stores the value of oItem variable to later open the forward, reply or replyall
 
Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange()

' the on error avoids the error in case the item is not mailitem

   On Error Resume Next
   
   Set oItem = oExpl.selection.item(1)
   
End Sub
 
'sub activated by the event of pressing "reply"

Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

' disableevents variable exits sub if its true, blocks the activation if myItem_PropertyChange() is working

On Error Resume Next
If disableevents = True Then Exit Sub

   Cancel = True
   bDiscardEvents = True
   
'displays the before selected email when the button "reply" was pressed

Set exception = oItem.Reply
exception.Display

End Sub

'sub activated by the event of pressing "forward"

Private Sub oItem_Forward(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

' disableevents variable exits sub if its true, blocks the activation if myItem_PropertyChange() is working

On Error Resume Next
If disableevents = True Then Exit Sub

   Cancel = True
   bDiscardEvents = True
   
'displays the before selected email when the button "forward" was pressed

Set exception = oItem.Forward
exception.Display

End Sub

'sub activated by the event of pressing "replyall"

Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

' disableevents variable exits sub if its true, blocks the activation if myItem_PropertyChange() is working

On Error Resume Next
If disableevents = True Then Exit Sub

   Cancel = True
   bDiscardEvents = True

'displays the before selected email when the button "replyall" was pressed

Set exception = oItem.ReplyAll
exception.Display


End Sub

' on NewInspector it sets the inspectors variables

Private Sub m_Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)

    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    
       'Handle emails only:
       
       Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
       Set m_Inspector = Inspector
       
       bDiscardEvents = False
       
    End If
End Sub

'on m_Inspector activation the subs sets myItem variable

 Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
 
    If TypeOf m_Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
    
       Set myItem = m_Inspector.CurrentItem
       
    End If
 End Sub

'on myItem Property Change sub starts, this subs checks for subject, if subject is equal to a specific value then opens a mail using a .txt file(with html code inside) to use it as a template

Private Sub myItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)

'variables necessary to pull data from .txt file and then put it inside .HTMLBody

Dim FilePath As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FileContent As String

'inspector, explorer and mailitem used to check for subject, open selected mail and then open the "template"

Dim exp As Explorer
Dim ite As Inspector
Dim selection As selection
Dim currentmail As MailItem
Dim selectedmail As MailItem

'active part of the code where we set the various explorer, inspector and mailitems

Set exp = Outlook.ActiveExplorer
Set ite = Outlook.ActiveInspector

On Error Resume Next
Set currentmail = ite.CurrentItem
Set selection = exp.selection

On Error Resume Next
Set selectedmail = selection.item(1)

'variable that lowercases the current item subject to make it non-case sensitive

Dim lsubject As String
lsubject = LCase(myItem.Subject)


'variable that gets user's username

Dim varia As String
varia = Environ("username")

'if cycle that checks first for ConversationIndex (to control if this is a NewMail) and if lsubject (lowercase subject) is equal to a value then opens the "template"

If Len(currentmail.ConversationIndex) = 0 Then

        If lsubject = "reso" Then
        
            If MsgBox("Vuoi aprire il template ""Reso merce non conforme""?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            disableevents = True

            FilePath = "INSERT YOUR PATH"
            TextFile = FreeFile
            Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
            FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
            Close TextFile
         
            currentmail.Close False
            Set it = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
         
                With it
                .To = currentmail.To
                .CC = currentmail.CC
                .HTMLBody = FileContent
                .Display
                End With
                
         disableevents = False
         
         Else
            
         GoTo endvb
         
            End if

        End If
         
ElseIf Len(currentmail.ConversationIndex) <> 0 Then


         If lsubject = "reso" Then
         
            If MsgBox("Vuoi aprire il template ""Reso merce non conforme""?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            disableevents = True
         
                FilePath = "INSERT YOUR PATH"
                TextFile = FreeFile
                Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
                FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
                Close TextFile
         
                currentmail.Close False
                selectedmail.Display
                Set it = selectedmail.ReplyAll
         
                     With it
                     .To = selectedmail.To
                     .CC = selectedmail.CC
                     .HTMLBody = FileContent & it.HTMLBody
                     .Display
                     End With
                     
            disableevents = False
                            
                            Else
                            
                            GoTo endvb
                            
                            End If
               
 End If
End If

endvb:

End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object

'function that recognizes if email is open (active inspector) or if email is only selected and previewed (explorer)

    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
           
    Set objApp = Application
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.selection.item(1)
            
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
            
    End Select
       
    Set objApp = Nothing

End Function


Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

'declaration of inspector and mail item

Dim ispettore As Outlook.Inspector
Dim mails As MailItem

'APIs to recognize the presence of attachments

Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

'variables for the attachment

     Dim itemcorr As Outlook.MailItem
     Dim miallegati As Outlook.Attachments

' setting the activeinspector and using the function Getcurrenitem() to choose for inspector or explorer, I use the error to avoid the errors generated from appointment items

Set ispettore = Application.ActiveInspector
On Error Resume Next
Set mails = GetCurrentItem()
On Error Resume Next

'variables that make possible the non case sensitive search in the HTMLBody of the email, the UpperCase stores the HTMLBody and the LowerCase makes the first variable lowercase

Dim UpperCase As String, LowerCase As String

On Error Resume Next

UpperCase = mails.HTMLBody

On Error Resume Next

LowerCase = LCase(UpperCase)

On Error Resume Next
 Dim it As Variant
 On Error Resume Next


 
'variables needed to check only the first email and not the previously sent ones

Dim testo As String

Dim range As String
Dim numero As String
Dim textcheck As String

Dim rangealt As String
Dim textcheckalt As String
Dim numeroalt As String

Dim textcheckeng As String
Dim numeroeng As String
Dim rangeeng As String
'variable that gets user's username

Dim varia As String
varia = Environ("username")

'variable  to print "allegato" or "allegati" in the msgbox
Dim msgboxvar As String

testo = mails.HTMLBody

textcheck = "<div style='border:none;border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0cm 0cm 0cm'>" 'text to check when email is correctly compiled and has got the line that divide the messages
textcheckalt = "-----Messaggio originale-----"  'text to check if email is sent from phone or if not correctly compiled
textcheckeng = "-----Original Message-----" 'text to check if email is sent from phone or if not correctly compiled and is in english

numero = InStr(testo, textcheck)
numeroalt = InStr(testo, textcheckalt)
numeroeng = InStr(testo, textcheckeng)



range = Left(testo, numero)
rangealt = Left(testo, numeroalt)
rangeeng = Left(testo, numeroeng)

'variables to find the possible attachments

Dim aFound As Boolean
Dim a As Object
   
Set miallegati = mails.Attachments
     
aFound = False

'if cicle that check the presence of attachment and if yes populates the variable aFound with True value

    If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        For Each a In item.Attachments
            On Error Resume Next ' to avoid the error thrown when no items within attachments have this property
            
            If a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN) = False Then
                If Len(a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID)) > 0 And InStr(Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLBody, a.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID)) Then
                
                Else
                
                    aFound = True
                
                        Exit For
                
                            End If
                
                                End If

            On Error GoTo 0
            
         Next a


 'if cicle that checks the desired portion of text for the word "allegato" or "allegati"
    If aFound = False And InStr(LCase(range), "allegato") > 0 Then
    
        GoTo singular
        
                ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(range), "allegati") > 0 Then
                    
                    GoTo plural
                    
            
                            ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangealt), "allegato") > 0 Then

                                GoTo singular
                                
                                    ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangeeng), "allegato") > 0 Then

                                    GoTo singular
                    
                                         ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangealt), "allegati") > 0 Then
                
                                         GoTo plural
                                        
                                            ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangeeng), "allegati") > 0 Then
                
                                            GoTo plural
                                                
                                                ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(range), "allegato") = 0 And range <> "" Then
                                                
                                                    GoTo fine
                                                    
                                                    ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(range), "allegati") = 0 And range <> "" Then
                                                
                                                        GoTo fine
                                                        
                                                        ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangealt), "allegato") = 0 And range <> "" Then
                                                
                                                        GoTo fine
                                                        
                                                            ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangealt), "allegati") = 0 And range <> "" Then
                                                
                                                                GoTo fine
                                                                
                                                                    ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangeeng), "allegato") = 0 And range <> "" Then
                                                
                                                                        GoTo fine
                                                                        
                                                                            ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(rangeeng), "allegati") = 0 And range <> "" Then
                                                
                                                                                GoTo fine
                                                
                                                                                    ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(mails.HTMLBody), "allegato") > 0 Then
                                                    
                                                                                        GoTo singular
                                                    
                                                                                            ElseIf aFound = False And InStr(LCase(mails.HTMLBody), "allegati") > 0 Then
                                                            
                                                                                                GoTo plural
                        
                                                                                                    Else
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                        GoTo fine
                                

                                                        
'lines that set the variable msgboxvar for plural or singluar word in msgbox
plural: msgboxvar = "allegati"

            GoTo msg

singular: msgboxvar = "allegato"

            GoTo msg
        
                'this last if checks for the whole text
        
LastIf:        If aFound = False And InStr(LowerCase, "allegato") > 0 Or InStr(LowerCase, "allegati") > 0 Then
                msgboxvar = "allegato"

                'msg that signals the absence of attachments and asks if mail has to be sent, if answer is no, a word application makes it possible to attach chosen files to the email
                
msg:            If MsgBox("Nell'email hai scritto '" & msgboxvar & "' ma non ne è presente alcuno, vuoi inviarla lo stesso?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then


    ' user clicked cancel
Cancel = True

                        
                        
  
                End If
           
            End If
       
        End If
    
    End If
    
    
fine: End Sub
```

I have left the other sub that check for the attachment just to let you see if there are any conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the [MailItem.PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange) event is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, `Subject`) of an instance of the parent object is changed. The name of the property that was changed is passed as a parameter. So, you may check the property changed and process only changes in the `Subject` line.

Second, in the event handlers like `Reply`, `Forward` and etc. you trigger the event by calling corresponding methods in the code:

```
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  '...
  Set exception = oItem.Reply
End Sub
```

Instead, you need to use the object passed as a parameter:

```
ByVal Response As Object
```

Third, in the `NewInspector` event handler the following code is used to get the inspector window:

```
Private Sub m_Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
  '...
  Set m_Inspector = Inspector
End Sub
```

Be aware, a new inspector instance is passed as a parameter to the event handler.

You may find the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article helpful.